# OpenCV Edge Detectors

Tags: image, opencv

I'm using open CV in C++ to try to extract the edges from various video sequences. I've tried using Canny and Sobel operators. I require that my edges are single pixel in width and continuous.

No matter how much blur I apply to the video before canny (and how I vary the parameters) I always seem to end up with unclear edges with small artifacts around the edge in question.

Are there any other techniques using opencv to extract better looking edges?

[image: Edges extracted from a video sequence using Canny, edges in texture file in locations of blur circles are connected and straight! However gradient changes i'm assuming in the texture causes these 'errors' in Canny detector]

Comment: edge dectectors are just a preprocessing step. after that, you want [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)

Comment: You might wan to post some code and an example image.

Comment: Also, the [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: findContours helped a lot thanks @berak, however still not there :/ That is why I'm asking about alternative to Canny, which will not have this problem..